# Ruby Reading file contents and pushing selected criteria into an array within an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, file-io

I want to make a simple Ruby program that can read the contents of a single html page and output two pieces of info into an array.

For instance, this is the webpage: http://www.trulia.com/real_estate/Cambridge-Massachusetts/

I want my output to be:

```
output = [ [Mid-Cambridge, $642,126],
[North Cambridge, $602,100,]
[East Cambridge, $611,436]
[Neighborhood Nine, $1,068,284]
[West Cambridge, $1,577,444] ]
```

I was thinking of doing something like:

File.read(filename).include?(each_neighborhood)

And from there, push each neighborhood and the price nearest to it in the html file into an array together, rinse and repeat.  But I feel like this might not be the most efficient method, and I am not sure how to achieve it either.

I also heard that the gem 'search_in_file' could be useful.  But it may not be necessary.

Comment: Have you looked at Nokogiri?  With that and open-uri, you could just read and parse the page, then using css selectors find table you want to pull and build the ruby array.  Depending on the page structure, it should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Nokogiri](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/), which is a great gem when you need to work with webpages and want to extract information from.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little script that does it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby         
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://www.trulia.com/real_estate/Cambridge-Massachusetts/"

web_page = open(url).read
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse( web_page )

neighborhoods = doc.css('#most_popular td.txtL').map(&:text)
listing_prices = doc.css('#most_popular td.txtC').map(&:text)

output = neighborhoods.zip(listing_prices)
puts output.inspect
```

The output looks something like this

```
[["Mid-Cambridge", "$642,126"],
 ["North Cambridge", "$602,100"],
 ["East Cambridge", "$611,436"],
 ["Neighborhood Nine", "$1,068,284"],
 ["West Cambridge", "$1,577,444"]]
```

Pretty much what you're looking for, right?